# Number of solutions for a given logical equation

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory, logic, problem-solving

I came across the following question while studying logic and cannot find a solution for it anywhere. I am studying by myself and think I just don't know exactly the right terms to search for it online (I'm not sure it is called a logical equation so excuse the title of this question in case it isn't):

---

Given the proposition $P$, it's logical value is defined as $[P] = 0$, in case $P$ is false, and $[P] = 1$, in case $P$ is true.

Consider the following open sentences defined in the set of integers:

$ P_i(x): x \le 5$

$ P_{ii}(x): x \ge 3$

$ P_{iii}(x): $ **x is odd**

$ P_{iv}(x): x \ge 6$

How many solutions does the following equation have?

$ x = [P_i(x)] + 2 \cdot[P_{ii}(x)]+3\cdot[P_{iii}(x)]+4\cdot[P_{iv}(x)]$

---

I've made this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6z1g3472/4) and from there, I can count the number of solutions through a loop. In this case I've looped from 0 to 1000 and it yields 2 solutions. Though I can clearly reason it wouldn't be possible for a very large number to work here, since these are all sums of multiplications of 0s or 1s, I am having a hard time articulating exactly why. How would you go about finding the largest number possible, in this very specific case? So you wouldn't have to loop through values of X too far off from it?

Comment: What have you tried?  As a suggestion to get started, look at regions where the rules simplify.  $x≥6$ for instance.  Do even and odd separately.

Comment: So, for this kind of question should I just try out some cases for x and see if it equates or not? Is there a way I could generally know the number of solutions without  it being trial and error?

Comment: Not sure there is a "this type of question".  It's a puzzle sort of problem, it should yield to improvised analysis.  No...I don't see anyway to count the solutions without listing them.  There aren't many relevant regions...the analysis should be very quick.

Comment: If you know how to program, you could write a little program to calculate the answer(s).

Comment: So, I've made this http://jsfiddle.net/6z1g3472/4/ and from there, I can count the number of solutions through a loop. In this case I've looped from 0 to 1000 and it yields 2 solutions. Though I can clearly reason it wouldn't be possible for a very large number to work here, since these are all sums of multiplications of 0s or 1s, I am having a hard time articulating exactly why. How would you go about finding the largest number possible, in this very specific case? So you wouldn't have to loop through values of X too far off from it?

Comment: @Delta If you view the right hand side as a function of $x$, the smallest value it could possibly have *independent of the definitions of the logical functions $P_{i-iv}$* is $0$ and the greatest value is $10$ (in the case that all the $P_{i-iv}$ are $1$. So you only needed to consider $x=0$ to $x=10$.

Comment: This example is easily solved with the methods of Derek and Rushabh.  In general, if you are interested in this type of questions, you may want to look at SMT solvers like [Z3](https://rise4fun.com/z3), which are meant to solve problems like these, espectially when they get more complicated.  Keep in mind that counting the number of solutions to a set of constraints is usually harder than finding one solution.  Often significantly harder.

Comment: @DerekElkins Thank you so much for this. Funny how it seems so obvious I should check the value for when all cases are true, but it didn't cross my mind before you said it.

Comment: Continuing from @DerekElkins's comment that you only need to consider integers from $0$ to $10$ regardless of the meanings of the $P$'s: Once you take a couple of the meanings into account and see that exactly one of $P_i$ and $P_{iv}$ is true, you're reduced to the range $1$ to $9$. So then I just tried all $9$ values of $x$. Admittedly, Rushabh's answer looks nicer, but I think mine might be faster to find.

Comment: I have edited your question for you to include the context that you provided in a comment, but next time do put all such context in the question itself, to meet [the site guidelines](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, let's observe that $[P_i(x)]+4\cdot[P_{iv}(x)]=1+3\cdot[P_{iv}(x)]$. We can check three cases:

1. $x<3$: Our equation becomes $x=1+3\cdot(x\%2)$ where $\%$ is the mod operator. Clearly, no even number can satisfy this equation, and neither can an odd number. So, $x\geq3$.
2. $3\leq x<6$ We can convert the equation to $x=3+3\cdot(x\%2)$. Again, no even or odd numbers can satisfy this equation, so we move on to case three.
3. $x\geq6$ Since we know any solution must satisfy this, we can convert the equation to $6+3\cdot(x\%2)$. So, $x=6$ and $x=9$ are solutions.

Hence, there are $\color{red}{2}$ solutions to this equation.

Answer (score 4):

Here's how this problem would be coded in the SMT-LIB format, understood by most SMT solvers.

```
(define-fun Pi ((x Int)) Int (ite (<= x 5) 1 0))
(define-fun Pii ((x Int)) Int (ite (>= x 3) 1 0))
(define-fun Piii ((x Int)) Int (mod x 2))
(define-fun Piv ((x Int)) Int (ite (>= x 6) 1 0))
(declare-const x Int)
(assert (= x (+ (Pi x) (* 2 (Pii x)) (* 3 (Piii x)) (* 4 (Piv x)))))
(check-sat)
(get-model)
(assert (not (= x 6)))
(check-sat)
(get-model)
(assert (not (= x 9)))
(check-sat)
(exit)
```

After getting the first solution, we add a constraint that forbids that solution and solve again.  When we do it again, the SMT solver reports that the constraints are now unsatisfiable; hence we know that we have enumerated all solutions.

Answer (score 4):

Other answers show how to get a full solution, with a bit of thought/work. But a very quick observation that narrows down the possibilities is that **since logical functions can only take values $0$ and $1$, the right-hand side can’t be more than $1 + 2\cdot1 + 3\cdot1 + 4\cdot1 = 10$, and can’t be less than $0$.**  So the only values you need to try for $x$ are $\{0, 1, …, 10\}$.

This is something always worth thinking of: when some complex function (like the right-hand side here) is built out of other functions, if you know restrictions/bounds on the pieces it’s build out of, then those will often give restrictions/bounds on the complex function.

(Justifying the bounds in detail: if $a \geq 0$ and $0 \leq b \leq 1$, then $0 \leq ab \leq a$.  So $0 \leq 2\cdot [P_2(x)] \leq 2$, and so on; so for any $x$, $$0 = 0 + 0 + 0 + 0 \leq [P_1(x)] + 2\cdot [P_2(x)] + 3\cdot [P_3(x)] + 4\cdot [P_4(x)] \leq 1 + 2 + 3 + 4 = 10$$
and so in particular, if $x = [P_1(x)] + 2\cdot [P_2(x)] + 3\cdot [P_3(x)] + 4\cdot [P_4(x)]$, then $0 \leq x \leq 10$.)

Answer (score 1):

In addition to @Rushabh Mehta's answer:

note that $[P_i]$ can be seen as a "classic" (aka Pre-Calculus) function. For example,  $f_1=[P_1]$ is simply the function $$f_1(x)=[P_1(x)]=\left\{ \begin{array}{rl} 1, & x \leqslant 5 \\ 0, &x>5 \end{array} \right.$$

Therefore, you can study the given equation $x=f_1(x)+2f_2(x)+3f_3(x)+4f_4(x)$ using all techniques you already knows for this kind of problems: considering cases (as in Rushabh Mehta's answer), drawing the graph carefully,...